# Fuzzing with Peach / XML

Tags: xml, fuzzing, fuzzer

I am very new to peach fuzzer and am trying to use it with netzob to fuzz undocumented protocols.

I have managed to export my netzob capture into a peach pit xml file as shown below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Peach xmlns="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach /peach/peach.xsd">

  <Import import="PeachzobAddons"/>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 1">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 2">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="0002156082020d0"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 3">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00004b604506092a8/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 4">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00004f60490"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 5">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="000051604"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 6">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="000054604e06092a86"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 7">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="0000003b6"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 8">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00003b603506092a864886f712010202020111001000ffffb6314265347828f5a40d17b141591fe59cf0b18de"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 9">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00004e604806092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff911f2c711d69f514a7dc7adecd86b3cd6ce05e475"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 10">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="000054604e06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff1d5f9ce00ceea13243c5421cd81fb87dfa741"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 11">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="0054604e06092a864886f712010202020"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 12">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00004e604806092a864886f712"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 13">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0000003b; Blob,0000004e; Blob,00003b; Blob,00003f; Blob,000048; Blob,000049; Blob,00004a; Blob,00004b; Blob,00004c; Blob,00004e; Blob,000050; Blob,000054; Blob,000057; Blob,003b; Blob,004b; Blob,004e; Blob,0050; Blob,0051; Blob,0054; Blob,3b"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 1_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 2_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,39; Blob,42; Blob,43; Blob,44; Blob,45; Blob,46; Blob,48; Blob,4a; Blob,4b; Blob,4e; Blob,51"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 3_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 4_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,07bd90dffa017c160d682ff9"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 14">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="0000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 1_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3b; Blob,60"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 2_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 3_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,5a"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 4_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 5_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0e1b50ff7fe84a5611bb6f19; Blob,7342741441bfd"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 6_0" valueType="hex" value="4f"/>
    <Blob name="Field 7_0" valueType="hex" value="a2"/>
    <Blob name="Field 8_0" valueType="hex" value="78"/>
    <Blob name="Field 9_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4674; Blob,5557309e88c847720db060"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 10_0" valueType="hex" value="e2"/>
    <Blob name="Field 11_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,455f33; Blob,e34783cfc19d"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 12_0" valueType="hex" value="78"/>
    <Blob name="Field 13_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,41579de370e213; Blob,f049176de877cf"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 14_0" valueType="hex" value="06"/>
    <Blob name="Field 15_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,df0000003b603506092a864886f7120102020e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 16_0" valueType="hex" value="0a"/>
    <Blob name="Field 17_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,440e80; Blob,c15eca30"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 18_0" valueType="hex" value="0e"/>
    <Blob name="Field 19_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3f8af49188e30bf641; Blob,af8cb4948fc1e568ee20"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 20_0" valueType="hex" value="d4"/>
    <Blob name="Field 21_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,9c20122104af02c0b1; Blob,c4bbf8a291d851977e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 22_0" valueType="hex" value="0000003b603506092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 23_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,49b4a9fd04228a80; Blob,e9f421b9237348c4"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 24_0" valueType="hex" value="88"/>
    <Blob name="Field 25_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0755a2deb56e533640; Blob,b2bf74"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 26_0" valueType="hex" value="df"/>
    <Blob name="Field 27_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0d4d253a6f; Blob,abb8e55841ef9d1b0a1b"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 28_0" valueType="hex" value="f0"/>
    <Blob name="Field 29_0" valueType="hex" value="5c"/>
    <Blob name="Field 30_0" valueType="hex" value="bf"/>
    <Blob name="Field 31_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,641433bdc801d225; Blob,86e8dbb612f3346e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 32_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 33_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4e; Blob,51"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 34_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 35_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,48; Blob,4b"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 36_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 37_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,73230a; Blob,7a626268f52ac341274381b4d8ae9ba6bb54f2ea"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 38_0" valueType="hex" value="5c"/>
    <Blob name="Field 39_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,a77fe37c9d29bd; Blob,d282"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 40_0" valueType="hex" value="a2"/>
    <Blob name="Field 41_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1f877e99; Blob,b5564cf0d6"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 42_0" valueType="hex" value="ed"/>
    <Blob name="Field 43_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,8ea6aedc85ab8e1667b7eb1534278678e4e5ba10b1cd5c42bb; Blob,bc"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 44_0" valueType="hex" value="d4"/>
    <Blob name="Field 45_0" valueType="hex" value="47e8ee411baf3e73f654a8c633a3fcdf4e4da34d31c576c7a0814f567a577f943add"/>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 15">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="00"/>
    <Blob name="Field 1_0" valueType="hex" value="02"/>
    <Blob name="Field 2_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,15; Blob,16"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 3_0" valueType="hex" value="608202"/>
    <Blob name="Field 4_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0d; Blob,0e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 5_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f71201020201006e8201"/>
    <Blob name="Field 6_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,fc; Blob,fd"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 7_0" valueType="hex" value="308201"/>
    <Blob name="Field 8_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,f8; Blob,f9"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 9_0" valueType="hex" value="a003020105a10302010ea20703050020000000a38201"/>
    <Blob name="Field 10_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,25; Blob,26"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 11_0" valueType="hex" value="618201"/>
    <Blob name="Field 12_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,21; Blob,22"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 13_0" valueType="hex" value="308201"/>
    <Blob name="Field 14_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1d; Blob,1e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 15_0" valueType="hex" value="a003020105a1091b074b52422e434f4da2"/>
    <Blob name="Field 16_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1b; Blob,1c"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 17_0" valueType="hex" value="30"/>
    <Blob name="Field 18_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,19; Blob,1a"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 19_0" valueType="hex" value="a003020100a1"/>
    <Blob name="Field 20_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,12; Blob,13"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 21_0" valueType="hex" value="30"/>
    <Blob name="Field 22_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,10; Blob,11"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 23_0" valueType="hex" value="1b"/>
    <Blob name="Field 24_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,07; Blob,08"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 25_0" valueType="hex" value="7368656c5f"/>
    <Blob name="Field 26_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,617268; Blob,626d; Blob,736b"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 27_0" valueType="hex" value="1b057368656c61a381ed3081eaa003020112a103020107a281dd0481da"/>
    <Blob name="Field 28_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,123076af151cbe1b5d9c2327ebf813e2a23d6a63b9b11946b4d2010fa421f84feede0818acdec41ffdadc0bb12723b974"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 29_0" valueType="hex" value="95"/>
    <Blob name="Field 30_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1e747a4feedd0cffb61f0c932451a6a13c13dca7330a582b6f4307e0116a2b69d8e160b5d1b1c"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 31_0" valueType="hex" value="10"/>
    <Blob name="Field 32_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,630f5c31e2b50bb5f4ed32cf8cdc418bd37dc68a6f0178; Blob,a1b9ace0f4b"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 33_0" valueType="hex" value="fd"/>
    <Blob name="Field 34_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1b3bd6b997b437; Blob,c2685c"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 35_0" valueType="hex" value="6c"/>
    <Blob name="Field 36_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4d5aaa95f155c77d8455131be6775369798b5e19bca9d478294837eb89ae20ee0987d29ad7ccce71841e9c0232d6e511; Blob,58fda2ec6d63724dec6648537215dc194f20040464; Blob,afb3e0"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 37_0" valueType="hex" value="df"/>
    <Blob name="Field 38_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,b99a17645f4ed6edc8d5a9caeb0230c9fb094481173"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 39_0" valueType="hex" value="a481b93081b6a003020117a281ae0481ab"/>
    <Blob name="Field 40_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,1413d2ec3ef9cfca20477f976cf863010f16657c8a2bb14478ff27c02c9c86; Blob,816de4c223b705c6b709be95974862d1; Blob,cc0092a9f840"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 41_0" valueType="hex" value="a9"/>
    <Blob name="Field 42_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,33a0b9; Blob,4a6484c9a3864633e3b16be02009bf27cb49342e3ab57224b71776969255b771b5e83d399efb539f6693e049834ffd159262ac; Blob,682d2aa11d18226d4f69116ecffc08714d97ea80056027ae239ca7d5894be945096790"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 43_0" valueType="hex" value="2b"/>
    <Blob name="Field 44_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,048b6f334ba9ad8a46ad671bb22f374010edf77d499ffb1045869a7dfeb34d7a51a1fc9"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 45_0" valueType="hex" value="e4"/>
    <Blob name="Field 46_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,08a7ad8e98da41c00c72abcc126d08f71d1084a8581c0d5f3a9467b788ce3b; Blob,4968eb79b0a6e3fce990b48b44ade10e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 47_0" valueType="hex" value="7c"/>
    <Blob name="Field 48_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,60804dec; Blob,b907e0f099b15b25c8dc99cdf61de6"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 49_0" valueType="hex" value="b9"/>
    <Blob name="Field 50_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,11ef93e6fdd81d46; Blob,b14f55178d1e3e3cfb5e436c7ee440591eac4e5d80271814564638c0ba8ca57abb0d95; Blob,f10e2d89fa06ead9848fa2937e2696fa"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 16">
    <Blob name="Default_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0000003b603506092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff49ca5ecd95ddb4e32601cf36a969d8c4ac90d31"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 17">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,00; Blob,10e8c00df5104c963358e158d8ba564a51456185973e09f446c5"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 1_0" valueType="hex" value="0000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 2_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,003b; Blob,3b; Blob,3f; Blob,49"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 3_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 4_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,39; Blob,43"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 5_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 6_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,2f4f69de92d2406caf7"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 7_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 10_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3b; Blob,4e; Blob,4f; Blob,51; Blob,6f; Blob,74"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 11_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 12_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,48; Blob,49; Blob,4b; Blob,69; Blob,6e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 13_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 14_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0b862a0ce85e06384318194b0553ff6f807f19648663e1d95ba04c23cc85bc2d6903a5a6b93caa873dddbc47ff30779195699743f623; Blob,1e26ffe960c0c6edb"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 18">
    <Blob name="Field 0_0" valueType="hex" value="0000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 1_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3b; Blob,4e; Blob,54"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 2_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 3_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,48; Blob,4e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 4_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 5_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3aa2b4c8ffa397b24c2de29938f19291b0b47f880407155f5132f1b72a9bab17753996c19e3ab30ad77117324b04095bc"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 6_0" valueType="hex" value="48"/>
    <Blob name="Field 7_0" valueType="hex" value="86f712010202020111001000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 8_0" valueType="hex" value="ff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 9_0" valueType="hex" value="b57717ebc7"/>
    <Blob name="Field 10_0" valueType="hex" value="ff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 11_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,28b250d30e6f3954c01caf98bc3646953e1ee588719615c38e14bb5233016f7b13d3fd0992aa18bb42966993ec890"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 12_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 15_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,3b; Blob,4e; Blob,59"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 16_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 17_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,35; Blob,48; Blob,53"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 18_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 19_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,239b07d3b7eb432c9196f5ae8405cbfd20937982708541249089fe72e28566367d679f10ea055bf5a37de9dd3e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 20_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 23_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4b; Blob,54; Blob,5d"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 24_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 25_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,45; Blob,4e; Blob,57"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 26_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 27_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,16f64a9ad58b52fa29c2810c; Blob,2e40ba6dc5d2035a20b7fb70b45920; Blob,50f12c3871c5fa76d250; Blob,da88af6ad2f983c95fd78a1d42989e249c1bd88c6cb53a7e5d46b9"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 28_0" valueType="hex" value="b7"/>
    <Blob name="Field 29_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,55af6437c846121b4b11de5f41fc37a11c9d562e8fb1c96a0dd8922804fe60d826dd5c6e678cbde8e6aaa7edab13; Blob,5732"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 30_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 31_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4b; Blob,4e; Blob,51; Blob,54"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 32_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 33_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,45; Blob,48; Blob,4b; Blob,4e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 34_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 35_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,00; Blob,394fb48bf0406c18cca03fca9efdeb1ba1bbed1f6c5a84dc7060ac0545232601eb497ffc95612f3b878"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 36_0" valueType="hex" value="89"/>
    <Blob name="Field 37_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,57a35e8f7352d30fecb25ee2; Blob,9beca343f443493d987fb00fa01a6b; Blob,a87"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 38_0" valueType="hex" value="000000"/>
    <Blob name="Field 39_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,4b; Blob,4e; Blob,54"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 40_0" valueType="hex" value="60"/>
    <Blob name="Field 41_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,45; Blob,48; Blob,4e"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 42_0" valueType="hex" value="06092a864886f712010202020111001000ffff"/>
    <Blob name="Field 43_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,0d11840518c9f6dac8c23a58233a4d; Blob,1084dd9a34d14fd8f43d83e8982166009404716fa47448dbcc49aaae; Blob,1b8743; Blob,f744dc8bf1fb1bf9b4bb8b80"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
    <Blob name="Field 44_0" valueType="hex" value="5b"/>
    <Blob name="Field 45_0" valueType="hex">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.Or">
        <Param name="values" value="Blob,310179cbd731aff665c09281571d4a50267f7dba85ee82cba0ce30f7f44a; Blob,6202c8a5c428f631a4"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <DataModel name="dataModel 20">
    <Blob name="Field 0">
      <Fixup class="PeachzobAddons.RandomField">
        <Param name="minlen" value="0"/>
        <Param name="maxlen" value="1024"/>
        <Param name="type" value="Blob"/>
      </Fixup>
    </Blob>
  </DataModel>
  <StateModel initialState="state 0" name="stateModel">
    <State name="state 0">
      <Action ref="state 1" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,19)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 2" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,18)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 3" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,17)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 4" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,16)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 5" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,15)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 6" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,14)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 7" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,13)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 8" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,12)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 9" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,11)==1"/>
      <Action ref="state 10" type="changeState" when="random.randint(1,10)==1"/>
    </State>
    <State name="state 1">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 1"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 2">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 2"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 3">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 3"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 4">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 4"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 5">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 5"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 6">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 6"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 7">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 7"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 8">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 8"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 9">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 9"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
    </State>
    <State name="state 10">
      <Action type="output">
        <DataModel ref="dataModel 10"/>
        <Data name="data"/>
      </Action>
  </StateModel>
  <Test name="DefaultTest">
    <StateModel ref="stateModel"/>

    <Publisher class="tcp.Tcp">
      <Param name="host" value="10.64.5.116"/>
      <Param name="port" value="50001"/>
    </Publisher>

    <Logger class="logger.Filesystem">
      <Param name="path" value="logs"/>
    </Logger>
  </Test>

<Test name="DefaultTest"/>

</Peach>
```

However, when I run `./peach test.xml` I get the following message:

> Error, unable to locate Fixup named 'PeachzobAddons.Or', FindTypeByAttribute returned null

Answer (score 0):

fixup works like this hope this help

```
<Fixup class="ScriptFixup">
    <Param name="class" value="{nameusedinimport}.{nameoftheclass}"/>
</Fixup>
```